# Magento and Wordpress intergration

Tags: wordpress, magento

I've been developing a Wordpress site for the last few months with the aim to make it a e-commerce website. I recently came across Magento and realised It is an extremely powerful e-commerce framework.

I was wondering whether anyone has any advice for Wordpress and Magento integration. Is it better to have Magento at the root as the CMS and use Wordpress for the blogging aspect, or is it just as feasible the other way around?

I was also wondering if it's worth me just creating a Magento theme based around my current Wordpress theme instead?

Comment: Check out the Fishpig module. It works pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the latter is the best option here.  I use Magento for an Ecommerce platform and Wordpress for the associated blog.  Each has their strengths and weaknesses.  Play to the strongest part of each and use Magento separately from Wordpress.  Believe it or not, you'll save time even though you are using both platforms independently.  Plus, Wordpress has been known to have minor to major security issues in the past.  Plus, I wouldn't put the engine that's going to be providing me with a paycheck in a position that it was never intended to handle --> ecommerce.